# return a complex object instead of ValidationResult in CustomValidation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, c#-4.0, data-annotations

I have a class like this :

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(Validate_Class_MetaData), "Validate")]
public class tbl_MetaData
{
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "-...")]
    [Range(1, Int64.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "-...")]
    public global::System.Int64 Id { set; get; }

    ...
}
```

and I want validate my class using another class:

```
public class Validate_Class_MetaData
{
    public static ValidationResult Validate (tblData tbl, ValidationContext vc)
    {
```

the problem is I Have some warnings with errors.I mean some business rules not errors and I want show to user that warings using a dialog box and if user want save records with that warnings. Now I cant return complex object using `ValidationResult`.

How I can return `ValidationResult.Success` and some warnings together?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the the [ValidationResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411789%28v=vs.95%29) class only supports either success or failure. From the link (emphasis is mine):

> **If the value of the member successfully validates**, the returned
>   ValidationResult object equals the value of the Success field. To
>   determine whether validation succeeded, you should check whether the
>   returned object equals Success. **If the value of the member does not
>   validate**, the returned ValidationResult object contains an error
>   message and a collection of member names for the validation error, if
>   they can be retrieved.

You could implement your own warnings by using a dedicated warnings element and adding text to it, for example, but ValidationResult does not support messages or warnings.